# WCF async implementation with 'normal' interface

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

Every article I have read about doing an async implementation for a WCF service requires modifying the interface for the WCF service (e.g. the return type of the operation goes from T to Task). However, I don't want to modify the operation signature as I have client code that doesn't know anything about the Task<> type. I just want the implementation to be synchronous.

I could implement the existing synchronous entry points by having a 'wrapper' method that makes a call to an internal async implementation method and then does an await, but that would block the thread calling into the wrapper, and that defeats the purpose of having an async implementation (which is to free up those threads so that they can serve other requests).

So, I need WCF to know that the implementation is async, but also know that the interface is not.

Comment: I think in order to do this, you'd need to use a different interface on your server than on your client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Asyncness" of the server does not affect the "Asyncness" of the client. For example on a project I am working on right now I have the following on the server

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/Example/v1", ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]
public interface IClientsUploader
{
    [OperationContract()]
    Task<Results> UploadClientsAsync(Database database, Client[] clients);
}
```

but on the client side I have the contract

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://example.com/Example/v1", ConfigurationName="Example.IClientsUploader")]
public interface IClientsUploader
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://example.com/Example/v1/IClientsUploader/UploadClients", ReplyAction="http://example.com/Example/v1/IClientUploader/UploadClientsResponse")]
    Example.DataStructures.Results UploadClients(Example.DataStructures.Database database, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Example.DataStructures.Client> clients);
}
```

And it works perfectly fine. WCF notices the `Task` `XxxxAsync` pattern and turns it in to a endpoint without the `Task<T>` return type and `Async` suffix. However when a operation comes in the operation can be processed using things like `await` inside it.

Comment: Interesting. I would not have even thought to try this since the service interface is supposed to be the 'real' definition of the service. Personally, I think that this is bad design decision on MS's part. They really should have left the type signature along, and used an attribute to signal an async implementation.

Comment: It makes good sense - and I'm going to have to give this a twirl.  I knew WCF matches by signature, not by interface (so that non-MS clients have a chance to play along) - but it never occurred to me that it would signature-match (what looks like) something so different.

Comment: To anyone reading this - you don't have to override action/replyaction names; as far as both interfaces have the exactly same name, binding of the client to the server will succeed. In fact, both interfaces could even be in the very same shared assembly, just in two different namespaces (the WSDL contract builder doesn't care about the namespace the interface is in).

Answer (score 0):

If your client can be a callback reference then you can use a callback implementation to behave like an async call. You only have to do is to add a callback contract to your service contract and implement it on the client.

Then you can call your service, in the operation on the server side you can start an async task (and return from the called operation imediately) and when the task is complete you can call back your original client via the callback contract interface.